# How can I Hide or Show Payment Methods depending upon Shipping Methods in Magento?

Tags: magento, payment

Please note that I am using IWD Onepage checkout extension it gives all available **Shipping Methods** and **Payment Methods** on one page so I cant use $_POST to fetch shipping methods in this case.

What else can I do to show selective Payment Method based upon a certain Shipping Method?

Comment: If they are on the same page then you will need a JavaScript handler to hide or show certain DOM elements. StackOverflow isn't here to write code for you but rather to help you fix what you've tried and isn't working. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an ajax call that will run on shipping method selection (radio button) that will update payment method and review total sections on the page.

thank you